# What is an external price?

Tags: microeconomics, economic-terms

I am only given a demand curve and an "external price" for the good, but I can find no definition of external price in any book. I am supposed to find the price and quantity of equilibrium.

Comment: "External price" could just mean an exogenously fixed price. But then it's not an equilibrium, so the question sounds odd. Do you have the exact wording?

Comment: just a guess: may as well be the price in the "external" (foreign) market. This would be an equilibrium but simply neither the consumer nor the firm in perfect competition can change it.